# Pagination for percolate results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, elasticsearch-percolate

I'm using **percolator** of Elasticsearch to matches user's query by a new document.

I thought the `percolate` also works with `from` and `size` parameters but only for `size`.

Is there any way to **implement paginating feature** for percolate results on Elasticsearch?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10741) still being discussed about this very subject. You might want to check it out and possible also [this one](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/13646)